# Android home button with drawer navigation stops to work with rotation screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, navigation-drawer

I have a main activity with navigation drawer and a button to load fragment.

When the main ativity is launched I load  the MainFragment.
In this moment all works well. The hamburger icon is showing and my Main fragment was loaded.

Next, I click a button and load a secondFragment. After I load the second fragment, I can use the backbutton and homebutton to come back to main activity without problems.

When I am with second fragment loaded and I make a rotation screen, the back button continues to work well, but the home button disappears and hamburger icon appears.

What am i doing wrong?

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
        private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
        private CharSequence mTitle;
        private String mSubTitle;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            initNavigationDrawer();


            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                    return;
            }

            MainActivityFragment mainFragment = new MainActivityFragment();

            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            //transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment, "princ");
            transaction.commit();

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Only handle with DrawerToggle if the drawer indicator is enabled.
            if (actionBarDrawerToggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled() &&
                    actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
            }
            // Handle your other action bar items...
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        }

        public Fragment getCurrentFragment(){
            FragmentManager frgmgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
            return frgmgr.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (drawerLayout != null) {
                if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if ((getCurrentFragment() instanceof MainFragment)) {
                finish();
            } else if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else   super.onBackPressed();
        }


        public void initNavigationDrawer() {
            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    FragmentManager frgmgr = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = frgmgr.beginTransaction();
                    Fragment cur_frag;
                    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                    switch (id) {
                        case R.id.home:
                            cur_frag = frgmgr.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                            if (!(cur_frag instanceof MainActivityFragment)) {
                                MainActivityFragment frag = new MainActivityFragment();
                                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);
                                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
                                transaction.commit();
                                break;
                            }
                            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                            break;
                        case R.id.logout_drw:
                            finish();

                    }
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    return true;
                }
            });
            View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView tv_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
            tv_email.setText("Agendamento");

            drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
            mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

            actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View v) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(v);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(v);
                }
            };
            drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

            if (toolbar != null) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        int i=getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                        if ((i > 0) || (!(getCurrentFragment() instanceof MainActivityFragment))) {
                            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // show back button
                            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    onBackPressed();
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
                            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
```

Main Fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    public MainFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button butCons= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.butcons);

        butCons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SecundaryFrag frag = new SecundaryFragFrag();
                // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
                FragmentTransaction transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left);

                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frag);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Secondary Fragment:

```
public class SecundaryFrag extends Fragment{
    public SecundaryFrag() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consulta_ag, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

After Rotation:

[image: After Rotation Image]

Main activty with main fragment:
[image: Main Activity]

Before Rotation:

[image: Before Rotation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is related to the fact that the view is recreated after the orientation change. I would take a closer look to the onCreate() from the MainActivity in particular when the

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   return;
}
```

is triggered.

One option is to retain the fragments and restoring them onCreate. Also you could turn off the recreation by catching the orientation and handle it yourself in the application, you can see here both options explained developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/

Comment: Yes, but I am lost what to do to fix it. Do you have some tip?

Comment: One option is to follow the google recommendation for retaining the fragments and restoring them onCreate. Also you could turn off the recreation by catching the orientation and handle it yourself in the application, you can see here both options explained https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html.